# When To Unregister Broadcast Receiver registered in onCreate?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In Android, I've registered a BroadcastReceiver in my onCreate(). Where should I unregister so that I won't have leaked receivers?

Answer (score 22):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

"You can either dynamically register an instance of this class with Context.registerReceiver() or statically publish an implementation through the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml. Note:    If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead). Do not unregister in Activity.onSaveInstanceState()."

:) The SDK is your best friend. I would say do what it says in the SDK unless you absolutely need the receiver when paused but be careful. Do you have to dynamically register the receiver or would putting it in the AndroidManifest.xml be better? If you put the receiver in the manifest you won't need to worry about registering/unregistering it.

Comment: Note that, starting from Honeycomb, the activity isn't killable until after onStop, so it is possible to unregister in onStop (with the corresponding register in onStart) instead of onPause.

Answer (score 4):

So far I have experienced 2 cases of dynamic broadcast receiver registering:

- You want the broadcast receiver to be registered only when the activity is on foregroung, by that I mean that the user is actually seeing the current activity's layout.

-> Then the broadcast receiver should be registered in onResume and unregistered in onPause. Normal case given in the official documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

- You want the broadcast receiver to be registered to receive a long lasting action has been triggered (most likely a Service) and the user can anytime pause the activity (e.g. the user clicks on the power button).

-> Then the broadcast receiver should be registered in onCreate and unregistered in onDestroy (confirmed by [How to unregister BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439041/how-to-unregister-broadcastreceiver)). If not, when the application will be paused the onReceive() method will not be called.
Be careful though, onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called (point raised in [Android - When to Register/Unregister Broadcast Receivers created in an activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887169/android-when-to-register-unregister-broadcast-receivers-created-in-an-activity)) so you will have to make sure it is called at some point (Activity finished), not sure it is the best practice.

Now why should it be dynamically registered?
If there is no good reason for that for this broadcast receiver then probably you should register it in the manifest file with the right intent filter to not be bothered by registering/unregistering anymore.

Answer (score 1):

When you are regeistering your broadcast receiver in on Create method it would me better if you unregister in `onDestroy()` method.it is just a override method get called when ever your app is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You should unregister it when you don't want to or can't receive broadcasts anymore.