# How to unregister BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My app uses a BroadcastReceiver to get sms in this way:

**SmsBR.java**

```
public class SmsBR extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            }
            if (messages.length > 0)
                //doSomething();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Activity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SmsBR">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

In this way SmsBR is always ON. I want to register it when a service starts (`onCreate()`) and unregister it when the service is destroyed (`onDestroy()`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

**Edit:**

**For an Activity:**

In order to register your broadcast receiver from within your app, first, remove the `<receiver>` tag from your AndroidManifest.xml file. Then, call `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)` in your `onResume()`. Use `unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver)` in your `onPause()` to unregister the Broadcast receiver.

**For a Service:**

Remove the receiver tag from the manifest file. You can then register your Broadcast receiver with the same method in the `onCreate()` and unregister in the `onDestroy()`.

**EDIT: Sample Code:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new SmsBR();

  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);
  }

  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
  }
}
```

Comment: So I've to use an instance of `SmsBR` and (un)register it? Which IntentFilter should I use for received sms?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Use an instance of SmsBR, preferably make it final, and register/unregister it. I've added the sample code for you. Regarding the IntentFilter, use pretty much the same filter that you had in your manifest file.

Comment: @WindsurferOak Hi, found this post very helpful.  I too have a class which extends broadcast receiver and need to unregister it.  I am getting an error with " registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);"  The method is undefined for the type CLASS_NAME" Can you advise?

Comment: Is it necessary to unregister the broadcast receiver in android?

Comment: Yes it is necessary to unregister it. Also, great example! One small addition the calls to super.onResume() and super.onPause() respectively are missing.

Comment: What would happen if I do not unregister the broadcast receiver? Would it remain active even after the phone reboots ?

Answer (score 26):

`onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called. When you start Activity from Activty, `onPause()` and `onStop()` method called instead of `onDestroy()`.

`onDestroy()` calls when you hit back button or call `finish()` method.

**Hence, broadcast receiver should be registered in `onStart()` or `onResume()`, and unregister receiver in `onPause()` or `onStop()`.**

If you unregister receiver in `onDestroy()` method, ***it might cause a memory leak in App***.

Comment: onStop is not guaranteed to be called either, therefore you should deregistert in onPause.

Comment: @barq not true. On API 11+ onStop is guaranteed to be called. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395169/is-activity-onstop-guaranteed-to-be-called-api-11

Answer (score 0):

First remove receiver tag from manifest,
then:
for service :

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {


    myReceiver = new SmsBR();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SMS_RECEIVED");// add any actions you want
    registerReceiver(myReceiver , filter);

 }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (myReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}
```

for Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new SmsBR();

  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);
  }

  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mybroadcast!= null)
       unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
  }
}
```