# How to unregister another applications' broadcastreceiver or to block them?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, block, android-broadcast

It is as simple as mentioned in the questions I tried it up with another app of mine and tried to unregister its broadcast receiver from my new app but it didn't happened. using th unregisterReceiver(kill2nd);

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439041/how-to-unregister-broadcastreceiver

Hi try this link 
it useful for you

Comment: To create a master app whose sub apps will have the authority to receive the data in its own database only, no spy app will do any tasks hidden.

Comment: I think you could do this by creating a broadcast receiver in your sub app that can receive an intent that tells it to register or unregister its other receiver. The receiver that you want to turn on and off should not be declared in the manifest but only registered/unregistered in the code of its own app. Your master app can just broadcast the intent that tells the sub app to do its thing.

Comment: I want to unregister the other apps broadcastreceivers e.g sms pro is working so I want to unregister its receiver hopefully its more clear