# How do I run my serivice on background and close BroadcastReceiver in Android?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I would like to run my service on background for a sms reader. 
Service is already running on background. But I wouldn't like to see App's interface, thought a method for this. I hide the activity_main.xml, and just want close(run on background) my BroadcastReceiver when it did its task and did not find a way to do this. (Btw my MainActivity class is empty).

Here is MyReceiver class with BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";

    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
    {
       Intent intent = new Intent(arg0,MyService.class);
        arg0.startService(intent);


        String messages = "";
        Bundle extras = arg1.getExtras() ;
        if ( extras != null )
        {
            // Get received SMS array
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );

            if ( smsExtra != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i) {
                    SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);

                    String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
                    String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

                    messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";
                    messages += body + "\n";

                    // Here you can add any your code to work with incoming SMS
                    // I added encrypting of all received SMS
                }

                // Display SMS message
                Toast.makeText(arg0, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

And here is MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Intent intents = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intents);
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally I came from here [How to unregister BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439041/how-to-unregister-broadcastreceiver) but I could not run their solution.

Comment: Do you want your BroadcastReceiver to not be running anymore or do you want it running in the background? `just want close(run on bacground) my BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Im sorry about wrong. Close app's interface automatically and BroadcastReceiver running on bacground.

Comment: I see. Have to tried putting your `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Service`?

Comment: Yes. But I had some errors about manifest.xml. I couldnt write MyReceiver's class into the service' class.

Comment: Are you trying to make a `Service`-only app?

Comment: Service with sms reciver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the receiver as part of the service's initialization, rather than in the manifest. That will allow your receiver to be bound to the service and continue as long as (and *only* as long as) the service survives.

**`MyService`**

```java
public class MyService
extends Service
{
    protected MyReceiver m_rcv = null ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate() ;
        m_rcv = (new myReceiver()).bindToContext(this) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        this.unregisterReceiver( m_rcv ) ;
        super.onDestroy() ;
    }

    // rest of your code goes here
}
```

**`MyReceiver`**

```
public class MyReceiver
extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    protected Context m_ctx = null ;

    public MyReceiver bindToContext( Context ctx )
    {
        m_ctx = ctx ;
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter() ;
        filter.addAction( /* Whatever action you need to intercept. */ ) ;
        // Continue adding all desired actions to the filter...
        ctx.registerReceiver( this, filter ) ;
        return this ;
    }

    // rest of your code goes here
}
```