# How to cancel notification of BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

My AlertReceiver class is creating notification service. How can i cancel a created notification?

Here is my code:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       createNotification(context,"Title","This is message body", "Alert");
    }
    public void createNotification(Context context,String msg,String msgText, String  msgAlert){
        PendingIntent notificIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context,MainActivity.class),0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_image)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setTicker(msgAlert)
                .setContentText(msgText);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager=
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Comment: I mean how can i write cancel method for this class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver) as a separate function to unregister the Broadcast receiver class from your class.

```
public void unRegisterAlertreceiver(){
     unregisterReceiver(this);
}
```

Comment: I would create separate instances of the broadcast receivers outside of the class.

Comment: Can u please write an example code. It would be really helpful

Comment: public class AlertActivity extends Activity
{
  private final AlertReceiver myalertreceiver = new AlertReceiver();

  
  public void onDestroy()
  {
    unregisterReceiver(myalertreceiver);
  }
}

Comment: Have a look at this link it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439041/how-to-unregister-broadcastreceiver