# Disabling BroadcastReceiver for Oreo?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

I have a receiver registered in my app's manifest file with action BOOT_COMPLETED.
There is a third-party library in my app and when it receives BOOT_COMPLETED action, it starts a service. Since there is background execution limits in Android Oreo, it crashes.

Now, I want to disable this receiver for only Android O devices. Is there a way to do this? Maybe just like @TargetApi but in Android Manifest?

I forgot to write that I cannot change library class, it's an external jar file.

Comment: try `unregisterReceiver(broadcastreceiver);` in your main activity if api >= oreo like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7439072/8867002)

Comment: but it triggers when boot_completed. the app is not alive yet nor main activity.

Comment: I am saying that , you can unregister receiver (since you have registered it in Manifest) if you don't want it when app is launched for the first time by checking the api version

Comment: @JyotiJK If it unregisters the receiver permanently, it solves my problem. But I could not find any documentation about if it unregisters permanently or while app is in memory. When the app is destroyed, do you know if it will it stay unregistered?

Comment: it will unregisters permanently

Comment: Ok, i will try that and look if it solves my problem, although i doubt that. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Library's code is not in your control, any approach won't work. You should ask the library provider to comply with latest OS.

You can try following work around:

- Register `BOOT_COMPLETED` in your app with high priority as follows:

  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" android:priority="999"/>`
- Start a Foreground Service immediately

This **might** allow your library to start background service.

Alternatively, If you have access to the BootReceiver class of the library, you can disable it as follows:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ComponentName compName = 
      new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
            <library_broadcastreceiver>.class);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
      compName,
      PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
      PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: I had a look at your solution and I think this should be best solution (disabling receiver class by code). Also my question may be possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529276/android-how-to-unregister-a-receiver-created-in-the-manifest

Answer (score 0):

It's too late for answer, but maybe it will help someone.
I found different solution, like in accepted answer you can register receiver in your manifest, but instead of `priority` you can specify `tools:node="remove"` and this attribute will be removed from the resulting manifest. Also I think it's possible to create separate manifest for Android O.

```xml
<receiver android:name="com.package.app.SomeReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"  tools:node="remove"/>
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```