# how to replace fragment programmatically with internet connectivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to do what I thought it was a simple task: implementing a fragment that display different views based on internet availability.
To be clear: try to start youtube app without connectivity, you will see a beautiful error screen with a 'Retry' button. When you click the button the fragment (of just the view, or something else) reloads and, if internet is now available, display the correct items.
I have two fragments inside a ViewPager. the one fragment have recyclerview and it retrieve data from firebase.I want the first fragment to display an error message and a 'Retry' button. When the button is pressed, just like the youtube app does, I want to reload the content of the fragments and display the correct stuff, if the network is available.
I don't know how can I do this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP8ic.png)
Please help!

Fragment_1.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle b)
{
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,group,false);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
    myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/Blog");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder>(
            Blog.class,
            R.layout.individual_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            myref
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: I want to make like youtube. I don't know how

Comment: and you expect to get the code here? it is way to broad for SO

Comment: What did you try before?

Comment: I din try any think . I add my main fragment code on my post.

Comment: I m asking, because I had answered this kind of question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51008101/5954635 try it and let me know.

Comment: if I send you my code can you implement this on my code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `replacing fragments` on network change just `create a view` same as screen provided by you add it fragment which has recyclerView. and on network change just `show or hide` this view.

Answer (score 1):

**Youtube**  uses a separate view like `retry`,  if internet is not available it hides recylerview. On the other hand, if internet is available in the device then it hides **Retry** view then loads recyclervbiew and automatically loads the list with **Swiprefresh** view. Ofcourse everything is happenning in **same fragment** not in separate fragment like you are asking. Suppose `retry` is **TextView**,  if internet is not available `setVisibilty` **Visible**.and **Recyclerview** `setVisibility` **GONE**. If internet is available then `setVisibility` for `retry` Textview is **GONE** and for recyclerview `setvisibility` **Visible**.

```
 if(internet){
        getDataFromserver();
        tvRetryView.setVisibilty(GONE);
        recylerview.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }else{
        tvRetryView.setVisibilty(VISIBLE);
        recylerview.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
```