# Service has leaked IntentReceiver that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm using a foreground Android `Service` to request a resource with Retrofit, via REST API, as a timer every 60 seconds. Such service is also running in a different process than the app, this is necessary so that Android doesn't kill it when falls into Doze mode.

```
public class ResourceService extends Service {

   ...

   private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      // create mReceiver (BroadcastReceiver)
      // create intentFilter (IntentFilter)     
      registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
   }

   ...
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // main logic
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);        
   }
}
```

When I logout the app, `onDestroy()` method is called, so `unregisterReceiver()` is called too. The app goes to the login activity as expected and the service successfully stops. However, logcat arises the following Exception:

```
09-18 09:30:06.627 849-849/foo.mycompany.es.myapp:externalProcess E/ActivityThread: Service foo.mycompany.es.myapp.resources.ResourcesService has leaked IntentReceiver foo.mycompany.es.myapp.resources.ResourcesService$2@7c90278 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service foo.mycompany.es.myapp.resources.ResourcesService has leaked IntentReceiver foo.mycompany.es.myapp.resources.ResourcesService$2@7c90278 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1222)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:993)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1348)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1328)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1322)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:630)
    at foo.mycompany.es.myapp.resources.ResourcesService.registrarReceptor(ResourcesService.java:104)
    at foo.mycompany.es.myapp.resources.ResourcesService.onCreate(ResourcesService.java:74)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3534)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1732)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

I have seen a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357566/activity-has-leaked-intentreceiver-that-was-originally-registered-here-are-you#answer-20982510) on the topic but it refers to activities. Such answer states `unregisterReceiver()` should be placed in `onPause()` method, but there is no such method in `Service` superclass which I could override.

Does anybody know what is the cause of the above error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: I didn't yet :-(

Answer (score 3):

Call  unregisterReceiver(locationReceiver) in onstartcommand

Answer (score 3):

Try unregister receiver before calling super.onDestroy()

```
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);   
      super.onDestroy();     
   }
```