# Communication with parent Activity, refreshing parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am not able to find best solution to the situation where child activity changes data of parent activity.

I have activity A containing a list of items. Activity A starts activity B to show details to the user. User can run action and create activity C. Activity C creates new elements for the list in activity A.

The data are held in database so there is no problem with passing the data. I'm interested only in notification.

**What is best solution to notify activity A that the data have been changed?**

Currently I am aware of 2 solutions:

1) Return result by activity B and C with `startActivityForResult(..)` and `Extras`. The result would contain message *"datachanged"* -> *true* / *false*.

- I don't like this one because I am not able to send the message directly

2) Always refresh data in activity A on resume.

- Isn't that waste of processing?

3) Send Intent from activity C to activity A (broadcasts)

The solution I have found which are almost certainly wrong:

4) Save in some global state

- There is no global state (am I right?). We shouldn't do that as there is an extra abstraction layer (intents).

5) use getParent() to use parent activity

- The parent activity may be destroyed and recreated on return

**Isn't there some other more light-weighy messanger system beetween activities?** Something like `Handler` and `Messanger` in Activity-Service communiction. Maybe there shouldn't be one because it's against design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use broadcasts or localbroadcasts in order to send notification / event from C to A.

It will look something like:
1. Activity A loads the data in onCreate.

1. Activity A registers a broadcast receiver to some custom action "com.mypackage.datachanged".
2. Activity C sends broadcast intent with the same action once it changes the data.

This way - if Activity A is still kept in memory - it's receiver will catch the event and will reload your list when needed. If activity A is killed - it will auto refresh the data automatically when it is recreated.

Some notes:
1. Do not forget to un-register the receiver in Activity A's onDestroy. 
2. You can use local broadcasts instead of broadcasts. The advantage:better performance and security (your intent will never leave your app).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887169/android-when-to-register-unregister-broadcast-receivers-created-in-an-activity this one says that broadcast receiver should be unregistered in `onPause()`. So it looks like I shouldn't use broadcasts when activity is in background.

Comment: Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html at the "Destroy the Activity" section. Since you want your receiver to operate when the Activity is in background - you should treat it as a bg thread / long running op like they say in android documentation. I do agree that in most cases receiver will be unregistered at onPause, but your case is a bit different, so feel free to use broadcast receiver and enjoy both better performance and flexibility.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Even if i won't unregister receiver I will not get the events because I am the one who generate them not other application or system service.

Answer (score 1):

Sending the message through B and C with startActivityForResult is the best way to do this.