# How to register and unregister BroadcastReceiver programmatically?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcast Receiver in my app:

```
public class Ringmodechange extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

My **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".Ringmodechange"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Is it possible to register and unregister a BroadcastReceiver with java code? This receiver is working in the background.

Actually, I want to register and unregister the receiver everytime a user clicks a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible using a [ComponentName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) and the [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

---

Enabling your [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, Ringmodechange.class)
context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager. COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

---

To disable it:

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, Ringmodechange.class)
context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager. COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: thank you bro so i should remove the manifest code and use this code or this codes is for register and unregister reciver?? can you more explane for me??

Comment: Nope, keep the code in the Manifest and use the snippets when you receive a user click.

Comment: Thanks this is work perfectly. but can you just explane for me what does this code work?? unregister the reciver or ......

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887169/android-when-to-register-unregister-broadcast-receivers-created-in-an-activity) covering this topic.

Essentially, in your `onStart` and `onStop` lifecycle methods is where you should be making your changes.

In the [documentation for BroadcastReceivers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), they discuss the lifecycle of the broadcasts as well as security implications.